# New endpoint in Identityserver 4 for Custom GrantType flow

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am using .Net code 2.3 and IdentityServer 4 and so far have implemented custom granttype=myauth by implementing my custom class inherited from IExtensionGrantValidator interface. When i request on /connect/token TokenEndPoint with grant_type=myauth i get the success response.

Now instead of /connect/token i want a custom endpoint say /custom/token for my custom grant type requests.
Please suggest